# How to rewrite url without # hash

Tags: jquery, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I've a anchor link like this:

```
<a href="test.php#someElement">Go to element</a>
```

I would like rewrite the final url: If i click the link in a external domain (ex. from google results) i would like redirect **not** to

> example.com/test.php#someElement

but to

> example.com/someElement.html (like new page)

It is possible use htacces or jquery?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to change the href of the `<a>` element using jQuery?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this on the client, or server? (hint: the fragment after the # is never sent to the server)

Comment: No, i dont't wont change a href target. I would like when i click the link i not redirect at url like example.com/test.php#someElement but at url like example.com/someElement.html (like a new page). i think server side, but i not sure, it is important that if i click the link in a external domain i want redirect to correctly url

Comment: As RowlandShaw has already stated, the fragment identifier is not passed to the server, so you cannot do this server-side. The only way would be to do this in client-side JavaScript - as a one off this might be OK, but this is not optimal and might not help SEO, if that is a concern.

Comment: Thanks a lot, yes i know, anchor not precessed by server. Yes the problem is SEO, SEO in the only problem. Have you any solution?

Comment: Just to clarify (in view of the answer given), these are presumably in-bound links from another site (you mention an external domain)? Or, as the code snippet suggests, these are actually in-page links?

Comment: Yes These are in-page links, but I do not have to index pages with URL with hash in a search engine lists. I start to think it is not possible do this, for example this could be used to index in search engine sections of a scrolling one page website with URL without hash. thank you all...

Answer (score 1):

First of all added a class="hashLink" for the each links which you want these behaviour.

```
<a href="test.php#someElement" class="hashLink">Go to element</a>
```

and added this script

```
$('a.hashLink').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var getUrlAfterHash = $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
    var newURL = getUrlAfterHash +'.html';
    window.history.pushState("", "", newURL);

    var idPosition = $('#' + getUrlAfterHash).offset();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: idPosition.top}, 800);

});
```

Comment: Is correct, you are redirected correctly, thank you. But then how can I view this page directly scrolled in #someElement?

Comment: So your requirement is, you have anchor tags with hash and on-click of anchor tag you want to change the URL as mentioned in you question, but the page should not reload or refresh, then the page should scroll to the content area of that id.

if this is your requirement, then I have updated the above code. but it will only work in your server of localhost (it should have http:// or https://).

if this is not the requirement let me know.

Comment: Yes, is this is correct! the operation has to be just that. is not important if the link is external or internal, of course if the link is external page not scroll, but I think i can solve with a function like $ ('a.hashLink'). trigger ('click');